# HtmlAgilityPack, loading all comments from specific page, including unloading comments

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net, html-agility-pack

I want to load all the comments from particular website into the `List<string>` created in the API controller. I use `HtmlAgilityPack` to filter text content from the HTML, but all comments has to be loaded by clicking `<input class=button>`.

Can I somehow enforce it in the controller a then acquire the comments using `HtmlAgilityPack`?

Comment: What do you mean by "comments". Can you show a sample HTML document?

Comment: Hi, I mean like comments to specific articles like for example here on stackoverflow.com. I handled this issue by sending specific get or post requests depending on the mechanism used on particular site.